# Custom field data - maintaining uniformity

Tags: contacts, custom-fields, custom-search, custom-templates

I want to add Educational information of individuals as custom field set. However I want the data to be entered to be uniform. In our organization, different people will enter data into civiCRM. Some may enter as "B.Tech" or "BTech" or "Btech" etc. How do I ensure same format is used in the database for all degrees?

Answer (score 2):

There are two options:

1. Set your custom fields as a (multi) select if possible.
2. Develop an extension that validates the input using a validateForm hook (or in jQuery)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, make the custom field a 'Select" or "Multi-Select".

I am about to convert a data set of custom fields that I initially made all "Text" over to "Select" for the reason you described.  In addition, it will enhance the ability to use the Advanced search to allow selecting one or more of the valid values to search in the selection criteria.